# Compiler invoking a certain method

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object circle1 = new Circle();
    Circle circle2 = new Circle();
    System.out.println(circle1.equals(circle2)); // returns false
    }
}

class Circle {

double radius;

public boolean equals(Circle circle) { // doesn't override the equals method defined in Object
    return this.radius == circle.radius;
    }
}
```

Why does the compiler invoke the method equals from Object class since the argument that I'm passing to the method is of type Circle? I noticed that if I change the declared type of circle1 to be of type Circle, the method equals from Circle is invoked.

Comment: Since `circle1` is declared as `Object` the compile will only consider methods provided by `Object` when deciding which method to call. Obviously `Object` has no method `equals(Circle circle)`, so `equals(Object o)` is called instead.

Comment: Object is base class of all classes. Object circle will call Object's equals method. In this situation, parameter `Circle circle` equlas `Object circle`. And when you change circle1 from type Object to Circle, method `equals` of Circle is called.

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler uses `equals` with the `Object` parameter which is inherited from the `Object.class` class

What you did is define another method with the name `equals` and parameter `Circle`

This line invokes the `equals` method inherited from the `Object.class` which uses the Object parameter

```
System.out.println(circle1.equals(circle2));
```

To make it call the correct one, update the `equals` implementation

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Circle)) return false;
    Circle circle = (Circle) obj;
    return this.radius == circle.radius;
}
```

Comment: Yea, I just want to know why my method isn't invoked.

Comment: I recommend adding a `if (!(obj instanceof Circle)) return false;` at the start of the method to avoid a `ClassCastException` when equals is called with something that is not a `Circle`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I already added those lines and then removed them to simplify the answer. Added again :)  @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Thanks :) BTW, the null check is not really necessary, `null instanceof <aclass>` is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(Circle circle) { // doesn't override the equals method defined in Object
```

the comment shows itself, probably change to this

```
    public boolean equals(Object circle) { // doesn't override the equals method defined in Object
        return this.radius == ((Circle) circle).radius;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the signature of `equals` in your `Cirlce` method:

You use `equals(Circle)`, but the signature of that method in `Object` is `#equals(Object)`, thus the method is not overwritten.

For that reason you should always add `@Override` to methods that should overwrite, then the compiler issues a warning if nothing is actually overwritten, like in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Joachim Sauer made me understand the problem.

"Since circle1 is declared as Object the compile will only consider methods provided by Object when deciding which method to call. Obviously Object has no method equals(Circle circle), so equals(Object o) is called instead."